# Detecting network connection speed and bandwidth usage in C#

Tags: c#, networking, performance, bandwidth, detect

Is there a way to detect the network speed and bandwidth usage in C#? Even pointers to open-source components are welcome.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Try using the System.Net.NetworkInformation classes.  In particular, [`System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPv4InterfaceStatistics`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ipv4interfacestatistics.aspx) ought to have some information along the lines of what you're looking for.

Specifically, you can check the `bytesReceived` property, wait a given interval, and then check the `bytesReceived` property again to get an idea of how many bytes/second your connection is processing.  To get a good number, though, you should try to download a large block of information from a given source, and check then; that way you should be 'maxing' the connection when you do the test, which should give more helpful numbers.

Answer (score 9):

You should be able to calculate everything you need from the [IPGlobalStatistics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ipglobalstatistics.aspx) class.

Answer (score 2):

If you only care about the negotiated speed, you can look at the NetworkInterface.Speed property

[MSDN NetworkInterface.Speed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.speed?view=net-5.0)

Comment: Not the accurate one