# Using C# what is the most reliable way to calculate network bandwidth speed?

Tags: c#, .net, bandwidth

Using C# what is the most reliable way to calculate network bandwidth speed?

I've found a few examples using `NetworkInterface`, Performance Counters, native Win32 code, etc. but they all provide different results and none seem to match what other, already existing, tools are showing.

Any advice on the most reliable method to calculate network bandwidth speed in C#?

**Edit:** To clarify I'm looking to know how much bandwidth a specific interface is currently consuming.

Comment: Load over time or snapshot load?  (speed v. velocity.)  Either way you probably need to look at WMI.

Comment: Speed/s. Something like you'd see in a download file dialog or in the Windows Task Manager.

Comment: How different are the results you're seeing? Can you describe how you're doing the tests? I can think of several scenarios that would result in different results, but they are all because of poor test methods.

Answer (score 2):

[Same Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566139/detecting-network-connection-speed-and-bandwidth-usage-in-c):

> Try using the System.Net.NetworkInformation classes. In particular, System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPv4InterfaceStatistics ought to have some information along the lines of what you're looking for.
>
> Specifically, you can check the
>   bytesReceived property, wait a given
>   interval, and then check the
>   bytesReceived property again to get an
>   idea of how many bytes/second your
>   connection is processing. To get a
>   good number, though, you should try to
>   download a large block of information
>   from a given source, and check then;
>   that way you should be 'maxing' the
>   connection when you do the test, which
>   should give more helpful numbers

Comment: Thanks, that's one of the methods I'm currently using. My concern is that I get different values using it as opposed to other methods and so I'm not sure which to trust.

Answer (score 1):

> Using C# what is the most reliable way to calculate network bandwidth speed?

The most realistic way would be to periodically send/download some small test file to/from a knowingly very fast server and notice the time it takes.

Comment: To clarify I'm looking to know how much bandwidth a specific interface is currently consuming.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing this - albeit it may appear to be cheating as such - create a hidden process using 'netstat -e X' where X is an interval for example, 'netstat -e 5' with the output stream redirected and monitor the figures under the heading 'Received' and 'Sent'... what do you think?

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Comment: I don't think of this as cheating, it's essentially the same as the answer provided by NebuSoft.