# determine available bandwidth C#

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Detecting network connection speed and bandwidth usage in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566139/detecting-network-connection-speed-and-bandwidth-usage-in-c)

Hi! I want to create a program that will determined the available bandwidth in C#? any idea.

ex.I download movie and watch video, I want to know what is my available bandwidth

Comment: possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/566139/detecting-network-connection-speed-and-bandwidth-usage-in-c

Comment: Your "available bandwidth" and the effective transfer speed are two completely different things. Please clarify which one you want to find out about.

Comment: you should look at all of the questions that keep getting closed on you, and see if you can learn something about how to ask the question in such a way that you'll get valuable answers.