# Detect internet traffic idle state using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am creating a web parsing application, to download some video files from user provided url, when the internet connection is idle.

How to detect idle state of the internet connection using dotnet framework C#?

Comment: ASP.NET runs on the server, but you seem to be talking about client code. Which is it? I seem to have missed something.

Comment: @codesparkle I started with WebApplication in hope that this would provide better framework support for dealing with network protocols. However, Since I am trying to detect outgoing traffic from the machine. IMO it would not matter much whether it is WinForm App or WebForm App. What do you say ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detecting network connection speed and bandwidth usage in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/566139/detecting-network-connection-speed-and-bandwidth-usage-in-c-sharp) (Check the 1st and 2nd answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of checking for idle connection you could use [BITS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb968799%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) via the [SharpBITS.NET](http://sharpbits.codeplex.com/) wrapper.